# How to get data from last JSON object?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to figure out how to get data from the last JSON object using PHP.

Here's a copy of a the JSON with 3 objects in it:

```
[
   {
      "url":"http://example1.com",
      "identifier":495755330,
      "current_date":"2015-12-30 17:05:45",
      "results":3,
      "networks":{
         "FaceBook":{"detected":true,"result":"no-result"},
         "Twitter Inc":{"detected":false,"result":"no-result"},
         "Pinterest.com":{"detected":true,"result":"no-result"},
         "Other Sites":{"detected":true,"result":"some-result"}
      }
   },
   {
      "url":"http://example2.com",
      "identifier":495755331,
      "current_date":"2015-12-30 17:05:46",
      "results":0,
      "networks":{
         "FaceBook":{"detected":false,"result":"what-result"},
         "Twitter Inc":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"},
         "Pinterest.com":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"},
         "Other Sites":{"detected":false,"result":"what-result"}
      }
   },
   {
      "url":"http://example3.com",
      "identifier":495755332,
      "current_date":"2015-12-30 17:05:47",
      "results":1,
      "networks":{
         "FaceBook":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"},
         "Twitter Inc":{"detected":true,"result":"some-result"},
         "Pinterest.com":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"},
         "Other Sites":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"}
      }
   }
]
```

I want to get the `identifier` for the last object in each array.  That would be `495755332` in the example above.

Here's how I'm getting the JSON data:

```
$filename = 'https://www.example.com';
$json = file_get_contents($filename);   
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

I just can't figure out how to get the `identifier` from the last object and output it to a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, if it's always going to be the last element in your array, harness [`end()`](http://php.net/end):

```
$filename = 'https://www.example.com';
$json = file_get_contents($filename);   
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$last = end($data);
// now echo
echo $last['identifier'];
```

If that fails, simply use the last element in the array:

```
echo $data[count($data) - 1]['identifier'];
```

Comment: Any idea how to store the number in a text file?  Like send it to output.txt so that file always just has the last number listed in it?

Answer (score 0):

The first case is using `end` function:

```
$filename = 'https://www.example.com';
$json = file_get_contents($filename);   
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$last_identifier = end($data)['identifier'];
```

the second case is extracting the last array element with `array_pop`:

```
 ...
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    $last_identifier = array_pop($data)['identifier'];
```

Comment: Any idea how to store the number in a text file? Like send it to output.txt so that file always just has the last number listed in it?

Comment: file_put_contents('output.txt', $last_identifier);